# Discounts in a shop

Tags: combinatorics, optimization, real

I came across this sign in a shop and thought it could make a nice puzzle. So you can buy items and get discounts depending on how many items you got. You can combine discounts and use as many as you need. I want to buy $n$ items. Is there a value for $n$, such that I need to use all three types of discounts to get the best savings?

[image]

Comment: It's [that font from H&Co](https://www.typography.com/fonts/gotham/styles) again!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> No, there isn't.

> As you can always favourably replace a 2 and 4 by two 3s the best bargain cannot contain 4s and 2s at the same time.

Comment: Correct and well done!

Comment: Moreover, you never want to use more than two 4's as three 4's are worse than four 3's. This type of things happen very often in real life. Sometimes I have to argue a lot at checkout.

Comment: Once a shoe shop had an event saying that buying two items and the third (cheapest) was free. I bought six items, and at checkout they made the two cheapest items free... I argued that it should be the third and the sixth being free, but they couldn't understand. In the end I separated them into two groups and checked-out twice...

Comment: My father once saw a sale of \$1 items at 4 for \$5. At checkout, he requested that the clerk ring them up at the regular price.